# Python 3 on visual studio code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So I have been looking online trying to find how can I compile my python program using python 3 on visual studio code. However, it seems that they are not much information out there regarding how to do it. Below is what my task.json file looks like. Is there something I am doing?

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "Python",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["${file}"],
"showOutput": "always"
}
```

Any advise will be great thank you

Comment: Anybody to help in this topic please?

Comment: Have you tried installing any extensions? The [top downloaded](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) python extension works well enough for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just checked and I do have the extension Python for VS Code installed. But where in my file do I put this shebang instruction as they mentioned "To instruct on Python 2 or 3 the shebang must be present at the top of the python file
!#/usr/bin/python2 or !#/usr/bin/python3"? Putting !#/usr/bin/python3 on top of my python file still does not run with python 3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In VSCode, you need to specify the Workspace that you intend to use to run using particular Python version.

Press "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Interpreter" and select "Python: Select Workspace Interpreter"
[image: Selecting Python Interpreter]

This will list the different versions installed on your machine. Select what you want.

[image: Select the Python version]

Comment: Thank you @PeeDi! I have been using pyCharm in the meantime as I could not find a way.

Comment: This sets `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"` in the user settings. Great, thanks!